# How to convert rows to columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I've the following query:

```
SELECT first_period, period, sum(num) trans_num
    FROM (SELECT (DATEDIFF(created_at, '2022-12-10') DIV 6) period, 
                user_id,
              count(1) num,
                MIN(MIN(DATEDIFF(created_at, '2022-12-10') DIV 6)) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) as first_period
         FROM pos_transactions
         WHERE DATE(created_at) >= '2022-12-10' 
         GROUP BY user_id, DATEDIFF(created_at, '2022-12-10') DIV 6
        ) u
    GROUP BY first_period, period
    ORDER BY first_period, period
```

It returns the following result:

[image]

But now I need to make it visualize like a Cohort diagram. So I need to restructure the same result as follows:

```
+--------------+------+------+------+------+
| first_period |  0   |  1   |  2   |   3  |
+--------------+------+------+------+------+
| 0            | 6230 | 2469 | 2846 | 1713 |
| 1            |      | 2589 | 742  | 375  |
| 2            |      |      | 3034 | 397  |
| 3            |      |      |      | 1207 |
+--------------+------+------+------+------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH YOUR_TABLE_DATA(FIRST_PERIOD,PERIOD,TRANS_NUM)AS
(
  SELECT 0,0,6230 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0,1,2469 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0,2,2846 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0,3,1713 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,1,2589 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,2,742  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,3,375  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,2,3034 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,3,397  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,3,1207
)
SELECT C.FIRST_PERIOD,
MAX(
   CASE 
    WHEN C.PERIOD=0 
       THEN C.TRANS_NUM
    ELSE 0
   END)AS ZERO,
MAX(
    CASE 
     WHEN C.PERIOD=1 
      THEN C.TRANS_NUM
     ELSE 0
   END)AS ONE,
 MAX(
    CASE 
    WHEN C.PERIOD=2 
       THEN C.TRANS_NUM
    ELSE 0
   END)AS TWO,
MAX(
   CASE 
     WHEN C.PERIOD=3 
      THEN C.TRANS_NUM
     ELSE 0
   END)AS THREE
 FROM YOUR_TABLE_DATA AS C
 GROUP BY C.FIRST_PERIOD
```

Comment: You can remove all the ELSE parts.

Comment: Or switch to `COALESCE(..., 0)`